# Exclude 0 values from being averaged in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula

When I try to use the `=AVERAGE()` function, Google Sheets  treats my empty cells as `0`. As a consequence, my calculated average value is wrong, see a [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dOnc.png).

Do you have a formula or any advice for this?

I found the formula `=IF(EW171=0,"",EW171/EW108)`, but when I try`=IF(EW171:EW180=0,"",EW171/EW108)` it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, Google Sheets automatically ignores empty cells.

If in your case it does not work:

### Use `=AVERAGEIF()` with the criterion ">0".

Sample:

```
=AVERAGEIF(EW171:EW180,">0")
```

Comment: Should `=AVERAGEIF(EW171:EW180;">0")` with a `;` instead of `,` before `">0"`

Comment: Hi @JordanMontel! Either it is `,` or `;` depends on your [Locale settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cchange-locale-and-time-zone%2Cchange-the-language-for-functions). In most English speaking countries `,` is the correct separator while in most european countries it is `;`. Your spreadsheet will automatically suggest you the correct syntax when you start typing a formula and it will automatically convert the syntax if you change the Locale settings.